# Can people picker resolve NTLM users only in an FBA extended

Tags: authentication

I have implemeted FBA with LDAP and NTLM Authentication, I want people picker only resolve names for NTLM users not for FBA.

Please help...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this exact situation is possible. You can configure peoplepicker to only pick from non-AD users, but not the other way around. Check out http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg602075.aspx. You might be able to configure it to a specific AD group, which may trick it into ignoring FBA accounts.